# [JBoss AS7]: where to set environment properties

Tags: encoding, jboss, jvm, jboss7.x, system-properties

I need to set the jvm system property `file.encoding` to `utf-8`, in my JBoss7 environment.

Where do I have to make this change? `standalone.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also set it from the JVM options

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.io.encoding=UTF-8 -DjavaEncoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 9):

There is a section in all the instance config files, `standalone.xml` as well, named `system-properties`.

You can define your properties like this:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="file.encoding" value="utf-8"/>
</system-properties>
```

Should the section be missing, just add it *immediately after the `<extensions>` section.*